# With Clause, Incorrect syntax near ')'. (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the with clause and I have recently run into an odd issue. For even simple queries I am getting an incorrect syntax error returned and I can't figure out why that would be.

Whenever I run code as simple as:

```
WITH table1 AS (Select value1, value2 from table1)
```

I get an 'Incorrect syntax near ')' ' error.

I was using this before without trouble, so I feel like I'm making a really obvious dumb mistake that I'm just not catching. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any SQL statements *before* this script?  For `CTE`'s, the *previous* statement *must* be terminated with a `;`.

Comment: Your statement is not complete.  You need to do something with your CTE.

Comment: If the line above is all of your SQL statement, then you have an incomplete statement, and hence an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a CTE - you need to select at the end of it.

i.e.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        value1, 
        value2 
    FROM table1
) 
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Additionally, having the CTE named the same as the table from which you're pulling from, is not a very good idea. You had them both as `table1`.

Comment: That isn't really the name of the table (or columns) I'm drawing from, I whipped up generic variable names to take the place of them for the sake of the question.

Thanks though! I appreciate it

Comment: What does that have to do with Eli's answer @JoshKraushaar?

Comment: @scsimon responding to the final sentence I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a part of `with as` ,in your case `with as` must follow with `select`:

```
WITH table1 AS (Select value1, value2 from table) SELECT * FROM table1
```